# Return partial result from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a class that calls a web service to retrieve data asynchronously. To improve performance I implemented a client-side cache which checks if the requested data is available locally. The class returns all data that is stored in the cache and calls the web service to fetch the remaining data.

Can I return the cached data to the caller and then proceed with the web call, or do I have to make the call and return the complete set of data?

In a synchronous environment, I could use `yield return`, by with Tasks and async/await yield is not possible.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't get the point. Merge the lists, which is the hard part?

Comment: What stops you from adding the remainder to a list and then return that list? If you want to "return" partial data, you _could_ use Progress. But I am feeling that would somehow "bend" the purpose of Progress (and I wouldn't _recommend_ it).

Comment: @MarcoSalerno The point is a performance improvement. For example, I have 2000 items which I can only request in 200 item batches, but 1000 items are already present in the cache. I want to return the 1000 items to the caller and then progress with requesting the remaining 1000 items.

Comment: @Fildor Maybe Progress isn't the right approach, but events could work. But this would mean no async/await.

Comment: I keep not getting the problem, return the 1000 items, then execute async request, then merge the results

Comment: _Maybe_ (I haven't had much contact with it, yet) the [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) is for you?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I think he does not want to wait until the result is complete. I am thinking he has something like a pipline in mind.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with `Observable` for some reason - you can use this library: https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable

Comment: Completely straightforward approach would be to pass callback function: `async Task MyFunction(..., Action<Item> callback)` and then call like this: `await MyFunction(..., item => { ... do stuff with item ...})`

Comment: @Fildor Exactly. Getting the cache items and then making a web request equals to almost no performance gain. I can parallelize the requests, but that's still much slower than a local cache. I'll look into DataFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the suggestions fit my problem perfectly, but a combination of them did.

At first, I created a pipeline with the TPL DataFlow library to fetch the data from my sources. The results were then posted into a `BufferBlock<T>` at the end, that was exposed to the end user as an `IObservable<T>`. This had the added benefit that I now can easily query related data via additional blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
 // in your UI
            var result = new ObservableCollection<Data>(); // this is your list to bind to UI

            IsBusy = true; // indicate that work is done
            yourDataSource.GetData(2000).Subscribe(batch =>
            {
                foreach (var d in batch)
                {
                    result.Add(d);
                }
            },
                exception =>
                {
                    Log.Error(exception);
                    IsBusy = false;
                },
                () =>
                {
                    // this means done
                    IsBusy = false;
                }
            )

            // or you can await the whole thing
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                await yourDataSource.GetData(5).Do(batch =>
                {
                    foreach (var d in batch)
                    {
                        result.Add(d);
                    }
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
```

Your data source:

```
  IObservable<IList<Data>> GetData(int args)
        {
            var result = new Subject<IList<Data>>();

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var formCache = await GetFromCache(args);

                    result.OnNext(fromCache);

                    while (moreBatches)
                    {
                        result.OnNext(GetNextBatch(args));
                    }

                    result.OnCompleted();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    result.OnError(e);
                }
            });

            return result;
        }
```

If you are using WPF, Xamarin.Forms or UWP, I strongly recommend [ReactiveCommand](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/an-example) which can return observable and do the whole IsBusy thing for you.